# Hyperlink with answers package

Tags: hyperref, exercises, answers

I'm using the `answers` package for an exercises book. I would like to create clickable hyperlinks (in the generated pdf file) from the exercise to the corresponding solution and back from the solution to the exercise.

Here is my `ex` (exercise) environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{extbook}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add,pst-math,pst-xkey}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\thmboxoptions{headstyle=\bfseries\boldmath#1 #2~,thickness=0.6pt, cut=false}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcounter{moncompteur}
\newtheorem[M]{exc}[moncompteur]{ \textbf{Exercise}}{}
\newenvironment{ex}{\begin{exc}\normalfont}{\end{exc}}
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{corr}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]{\par\bigskip\noindent {\bfseries Solution  of exercise #1}\quad}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Also, You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism provided by the `hyperref` package. A little example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{moncompteur}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{%
  \hyperlink{ex:\theex}{Exercise}\hypertarget{sol:\theex}{}}
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{corr}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]
  {\par\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries \hypertarget{ex:#1}{}\hyperlink{sol:#1}{Solution  of exercise #1}}\quad}
  {\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{corr}[ans1]
\section{Problems}
\begin{ex}
First exercise.
\begin{sol}
First solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Second exercise.
\begin{sol}
Second solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{corr}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

Note that I modified the definition of the `ex` theorem-like structure using `\theoremstyle{definition}` from the `amsthm` package and removed the counter `moncompteur`.

Comment: Thanks a lot: you made my day (I went back to my definition of ex in order to use thmbox).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've been trying to do the same with `thmtools`' hooks, which one can define in `declaretheorem`. Something like `postheadhook={\hypertarget{exe:\theexercise}{}}`, etc., but the links and targets are all wrong. Is there a way to make it work that way?

Comment: @Dominique Please feel free to open a fresh new question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How can I \newtheorem{ex}[section] and Can I use your code with `ntheorem` package?

Answer (score 2):

Add `hyperref`'s `\phantomsection` to your definition of the `Soln` environment:

```
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]{\par\bigskip\noindent\phantomsection {\bfseries Solution  of exercise #1}\quad}{}
```

Now, in your document, using `\hyperref[<reference>]{<text>}` will jump you to the appropriate hyperlink/label given for the solution. For example, try the following:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}
Here is an exercise. Solution is \hyperref[sol:first]{here}. \label{ex:first}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Here is another exercise. Solution is \hyperref[sol:second]{here}. \label{ex:second}
\end{ex}

\newpage

\begin{Soln}{\ref{ex:first}}
Here is the solution. \label{sol:first}
\end{Soln}

\begin{Soln}{\ref{ex:second}}
Here is the solution. \label{sol:second}
\end{Soln}
```