# Hyperref with answers [ntheorem]

Tags: hyperref, environments, ntheorem, answers

I read [Hyperlink with answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26543/hyperlink-with-answers-package) and have tried to apply the technique to my environments that I have defined using the `ntheorem` package.

In the MWE below the answer links correctly go to the questions, but the questions do not go to the answers. How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{hanging}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{\hyperlink{soln:##2}{##2}}]}% 
\makeatother

% problem environment
\newlength{\problabel}
\theoremstyle{hanging}
\theoremprework{%
\hypertarget{prob:\theproblem}{}%
\settowidth{\problabel}{\textbf{\theproblem} }%
\begin{adjustwidth}{\problabel}{}}
\theorempostwork{\end{adjustwidth}}
\newtheorem{problem}{}

% solution environment
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{solutionfilehandle}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]
  {\par{ \hyperlink{prob:#1}{#1}}\quad\hypertarget{soln:#1}{}}%
  {}

\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{solutionfilehandle}[ans1]

\section{Problems}
\begin{problem}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{sol}
        First solution.
    \end{sol}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{sol}
        second solution.
    \end{sol}
\end{problem}

\Closesolutionfile{solutionfilehandle}
\newpage
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
    \end{document}
```

EDIT: It also helped to have the target first:

```
    % solution environment
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{solutionfilehandle}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]
  {\par\hypertarget{soln:#1}{}\hyperlink{prob:#1}{#1}\quad}%
  {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled your MWE (TeXlive 2011), and it worked just fine: questions link to answers, and answers link to questions. Did you make a rerun? Could you add a `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` and post the result (especially: which hyperref version did you use)?

Comment: Thanks very much, that did it. I also changed my compile method from `pdflatex` to `LaTeX`, and changed the position of the anchor (see edit above)