# Making hyperref, cleveref, and answers work together

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, hyperlink, answers

I am using the following packages in a math textbook that I am writing:

- The answers package to be able to put solutions to problems at the end of the book
- The hyperref package to be able to link problems to solutions and vice versa, and to refer to different components of the book, such as theorems.
- The cleveref package to conveniently refer to parts of the document, specifically having the "Lemma" or "Theorem" part automatically put in.

There are two issues:

1. References to problems are showing up as, for example, "problem:1.14Problem 1.13" whereas I only want the second part. This might be related to the error "Argument of \hyperlink has an extra }." whenever I internally reference a problem with \cref
2. The hyperlink that goes from problems to solutions does not cover the counter of the Problem environment.

Here are the relevant parts of the code. Please help me to rectify the issues.

```
\documentclass[openany, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\usepackage{answers, xpatch}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{%
\hyperlink{problem:\theproblem}{Problem}\hypertarget{probsol:\theproblem}{}}
\Newassociation{probsol}{Solution}{ans}
\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]
{\par\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries \hyperlink{probsol:#1}{Solution #1.}\hypertarget{problem:#1}{}}\quad}
{\par\bigskip}


\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\corollaryautorefname}{Corollary}
\newcommand{\conjectureautorefname}{Conjecture}
\newcommand{\problemautorefname}{Problem}
\newcommand{\exampleautorefname}{Example}
\newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]

\chapter{First}

\begin{problem}\label{prb:example-prob}
This is a problem.
    \begin{probsol}
    This is a solution.
    \end{probsol}
\end{problem}

I am referring to \cref{prb:example-prob}.

\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\chapter*{Solutions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Solutions}
\input{ans1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't show only snippets. Always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Please follow Ulrike‘s request. Thanks

Comment: @UlrikeFischer got it, I have added a minimum working example.

Comment: don't put hyper-commands (and other complicated commands) in the second argument of newtheorem. cleveref uses the text to create the references.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how can I get the problem and solution to hyperlink to each other then? I was following the example in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26543/hyperlink-with-answers-package

Comment: define the names explicitly: `\crefname{problem}{Problem}{Problems}
\Crefname{problem}{Problem}{Problems}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Brilliant! It works. One other thing: Any idea how to get the hyperlink of the Problem (that leads to the solution) to cover the counter? Right now, it just covers the environment name, Problem. Also, feel free to post your insights as a full answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't think that's easily doable using `amsthm`. You could just define a separate `problem` environment, not using `amsthm`.

Comment: Also, I know you just copied the code from the other answer, but the way your hypertarget/hyperlink labels work are backwards. Everywhere you have `probsol` it should be `problem` and vice versa. (Right now the Problem itself is labeled with a hypertarget `probsol`, and the Solution is labeled with `problem`.)

Comment: One further comment: your design choice is very poor practice when it comes to accessibility. You are placing in pairs of hyperlinks whose corresponding text actually is the "opposite" of what the link is doing. (The link points to the solution, while the text says problem.) I would advocate that you automatically generate text to append to the end of the problem environment that reads something like "(Solution on pg ??)" and have that hyperlinked to the solution. Including the page number also makes it easier for readers on non-electronic media....

Comment: ... and similarly for the solutions it would be better to have the heading be "Solutions to Problem x.x" with only the Problem x.x being a hyperlink to the original problem.