# Hyperlink in answers package does not include number

Tags: hyperlink, answers

For the stackexchange question [Hyperlink with answers package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26543/hyperlink-with-answers-package), the first answer gives a MWE which does not include the number.

The given MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{moncompteur}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{%
  \hyperlink{ex:\theex}{Exercise}\hypertarget{sol:\theex}{}}
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{corr}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]
  {\par\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries \hypertarget{ex:#1}{}\hyperlink{sol:#1}{Solution  of exercise #1}}\quad}
  {\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{corr}[ans1]
\section{Problems}
\begin{ex}
First exercise.
\begin{sol}
First solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Second exercise.
\begin{sol}
Second solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{corr}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

A picture of the output:

[image]

How should I modify the `ex` environment to include the numbering as well? (So the hyperlink is inclusive of 1 in Exercise 1 etc.)

Edit: So as seen in the pdf output, the hyperlink red box circles the "Exercise" title, but does not circle the "1", while in the solution section, the hyperlink circles both "Solution" and "1". How could I get the link to circle for the exercise section?

Comment: Welcome. // I think you posted all relevant code. However, I do not understand waht you mean by "does not include the number". Can you please Edit your question and give a short verbal example, what you expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new theoremstyle, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{moncompteur}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}%
{}{}%
{}{}%
{\bfseries}{.}%
{ }%
{\hyperlink{ex:#2}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{(#3)}}\hypertarget{sol:#2}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{corr}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]
  {\par\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries \hypertarget{ex:#1}{}\hyperlink{sol:#1}{Solution  of exercise #1}}\quad}
  {\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{corr}[ans1]
\section{Problems}
\begin{ex}
First exercise.
\begin{sol}
First solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Second exercise.
\begin{sol}
Second solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{corr}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

[image]